# How django template url matching works

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to figure out how url matching works in django template.
What i'm trying to achieve is when clicking on a link it would bring up a specific objects.

**Models.py**

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PostManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('published','Published'),
                        ('draft','Draft '))
    FIELD_CHOICES = (('1','1 Title and body field'),
                    ('2','2 Title and body fields'),
                    ('3','3 Title and body fields'),
                    ('4', '4 Title and body fields'),
                    ('5', '5 Title and body fields'))

    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='blog_post')


    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_title = models.TextField(max_length=50,default="")

    title_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    title_1_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)


    title_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    title_2_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)


    title_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    title_3_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)



    title_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    title_4_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)


    title_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    title_5_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

    created = models.DateField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='created')

    status = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                    choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                    default='draft')


    object = models.Manager()
    postManager = PostManager()


    class Meta():
        ordering = ('publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',
                        args=[self.slug])

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = Post.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "media/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='images')

    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,default='123.jpg',verbose_name="Image",null=True)
    image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,default='123.jpg',verbose_name="Image",null=True)
    image_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,default='123.jpg',verbose_name="Image",null=True)
    image_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,default='123.jpg',verbose_name="Image",null=True)
    image_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,default='123.jpg',verbose_name="Image",null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def post_detail(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post)
    return render(request, 'blog_application/templates/single.html',
                            {'post':post})
```

**index.html**

```
{% for elem in posts %}

                <p class="mb-md-5">A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia</p>
                    <p><a href="{ url elem.get_absolute_url }" class="btn btn-black px-3 px-md-4 py-3">Read More <span class="icon-arrow_forward ml-lg-4"></span></a></p>

            {% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('post_detail/<slug:slug>',views.post_detail,name='single'),
path('', views.show_index, name='index'),
```

I don't quite understand how url matching and linking works for templates. Could some one be kind enough to explain based on my example.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues in your view:

```py
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog_application/templates/single.html',
                            {'post':post})
```

on a more general note, you receive the `slug` value from the url and pass it to your view with the argument.

Also, you need to pass the argument to `get_object_or_404` see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

Answer (score 0):

before I dive, Let's agree that a slug is just a fancy name, It's just a string nothing else.

*Ok so you want to understand how django urls work.* **back off plz**

- Let's first understand how URLs work, let's say I'll open this website www.example.com & just open it as is, The website just opens right? You expect the home page to be there
- Now, let's open it as www.example.com?text=welcome

Press F12 in chrome & switch to networks tab, Essentially what happens is that you added a parameter which appears in chrome as 'query string parameter' at the very bottom of the networks tab, This says you wanted to visit this website with a parameter called text that contains the string hello

**Ok**, now what's the relation between this & the question? bear with me please

Imagine I have a social website with posts & I want to create a code "slug" for each post so that when It's typed as a parameter in the URL, It gets that specific post

now, this is your urlpatterns.py

```
path('post_detail/<slug:slug>', views.post_detail, name='single'),
path('', views.show_index, name='index'),
```

I'll assume that this is the project level urls.py for simplicity.

The user visits the website without any url params or subpages, it just calls your `views.show_index`

now the user visits your `website/post_detail/`, What happens is sees if there's any urlpattern in urlpatterns that matches this, but it doesn't, so it's just a 404

now the user visits your `website/post_detail/ANY_RANDOM_TEXT`

What happens is that there's actually a urlpattern that matches `website/post_detail/ANY_RANDOM_TEXT`
which `path('post_detail/<slug:slug>', views.post_detail, name='single')`

therefore, the "ANY_RANDOM_TEXT" must be the slug, Let's take it as the slug then!

now we have the slug, and the urlpattern will call views.post_detail (function or view) and pass the slug to it, so we must accept it right?

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog_application/templates/single.html',
                            {'post':post})
```

now you have access to the 'slug' which is just "ANY_RANDOM_TEXT" because we matched it, now get the post with slug that's the same as the slug in the url & just render it!

**Btw don't forget the slash at the end of any urlpattern or otherwise the world is gonna explode**

Comment: Glad it helped, Mark as the answer if this's what you were after